# jmeter error on opening script

Tags: jmeter

Okay - I have not moved this test from one machine to another.  This test was created and saved exactly where I am trying to open it today.  Yesterday - I made a couple changes and saved it.  Now, I go to open and I get the Error - See log file.

I have been searching for answers, but the only thing I have found relate to moving a test from one machine to another.  This looks like it is just plain corrupted.  Two questions - 1.  Anyone ever see this before and know what caused it?
2.  Am I screwed?  Do I have to completely redo this test?

Not sure if this matters in this case, but:
Windows 7
Jmeter 2.9

Here is the log information:

```
2013/02/21 14:54:53 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\Users\jcraig\Desktop\Tools\jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.9\apache-jmeter-2.9\bin\MC_multi_thread.jmx 
2013/02/21 14:54:53 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Users\jcraig\Desktop\Tools\jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.9\apache-jmeter-2.9\bin' 
2013/02/21 14:54:53 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Users\jcraig\Desktop\Tools\jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.9\apache-jmeter-2.9\bin' 
2013/02/21 14:55:40 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\Users\jcraig\Desktop\Tools\jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.9\apache-jmeter-2.9\bin\MC_Multi_Thread02.jmx 
2013/02/21 14:55:40 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Users\jcraig\Desktop\Tools\jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.9\apache-jmeter-2.9\bin' 
2013/02/21 14:55:40 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24 :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24
---- Debugging information ----
message             :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException
cause-message       :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24
class               : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBaseConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/hashTree[4]/HTTPSamplerProxy[16]
line number         : 7282
class[1]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
------------------------------- :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24 :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24
---- Debugging information ----
message             :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException
cause-message       :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24
class               : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBaseConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/hashTree[4]/HTTPSamplerProxy[16]
line number         : 7282
class[1]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
-------------------------------
message             :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24 :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24
---- Debugging information ----
message             :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException
cause-message       :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24
class               : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBaseConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/hashTree[4]/HTTPSamplerProxy[16]
line number         : 7282
class[1]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24 :  : no more data available - expected end tags </stringProp></HTTPSamplerProxy></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></hashTree></jmeterTestPlan> to close start tag <stringProp> from line 7281 and start tag <HTTPSamplerProxy> from line 7257 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6253 and start tag <hashTree> from line 6191 and start tag <hashTree> from line 13 and start tag <hashTree> from line 3 and start tag <jmeterTestPlan> from line 2, parser stopped on TEXT seen ...</stringProp>\n            <stringProp... @7282:24
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:65)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/hashTree[4]/HTTPSamplerProxy[16]
line number         : 7282
version             : 2.9 r1437961
------------------------------- 
2013/02/21 14:55:40 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.Exception: Error in TestPlan - see log file
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:158)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:113)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.LoadRecentProject.doAction(LoadRecentProject.java:68)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Thanks for any info on this!

Jamie

Comment: What might the issue have been if you'd moved it from one machine to another?

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps

1. Go to below link
   https://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/
   and add plugin manager to your Jmeter
2. Restart Jmeter
3. Add required plugin by clicking on "options --> Plugins Manager"
4. Restart Jmeter

I think it can resolve your issue

Comment: This actually worked. It downloaded the plugins I was missing.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks. Just open the jmx file again, plugin managed detected the missing plugins and you can download them. Great.

Comment: This worked for me as well! I was initially unable to read json info and after using the plugin manager to download the Json path formatter, I was unblocked! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is a quick way to bonify your corrupted test jmx file.

1. Go to your jmeter directory and open jmeter.log file
2. The lastest rows rapresents the last error jmeter logged, you have to find a block like this:

   ---- Debugging information ----
   message             : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.rest.RestSampler
   cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
   cause-message       : com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.rest.RestSampler
   class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
   required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
   converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
   path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[3]/hashTree[3]/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.rest.RestSampler
   **line number         : 950**
3. Open your jmx corrupted file with a text editor and find the corrupted line of code (in the above example the corrupted line is 950)
4. Remove the entire tag from `<tag.name>` to `</tag.name>` (or if you are enought skilled try to surf into child tags, find the bug and fix it)
5. Save your edited file with a different name
6. Load into jmeter
7. If the error persist, repeat from step 1 (you'll find a new tag to remove)

Comment: This also works if you have a different plugin version than the original, and it added/removed tags that jmeter is choking on.

Comment: Found my log under `~/jmeter.log`

Answer (score 3):

We came across a similar issue when trying to open a test using JMeter 2.13. This was resolved by adding some JMeter plugins.

In our case we needed to add the 'JMeterPlugins-Standard' jar in lib/ext folder for `kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.ResponseTimesOverTimeGui` (OR `kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector` ) usage in the test.

Also we needed to add the `jmeter-plugins-1.0.0` jar in lib/junit folder for `com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.rest.gui.RestGui` (OR `com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.rest.RestSampler`) usage.

In this case you need to look for the line 7282 in your test to see what it is missing and add the relevant plugin for it.

For some reason these jar files are not included with the default jmeter download.

Hope that helps.

Comment: While other dependencies can be resolved automatically with plugin manager, this RestSampler is only available in `jmeter-plugins-1.0.0.jar`. Google it and download it from some bizarre sites works. Yes, it's not among jmeter-plugins.org

Answer (score 1):

It seems your file is corrupt.

Try to open it in an xml editor to see if it is correct.

Check disk space or disk issue. Did you have a crash during a save ?

You can try to add manually end of tags to get part of it back, maybe you will need to remove last  xml node.

Comment: Must have had an error during saving.  When I opened as XML, I could see the missing tags. Thanks!

Comment: Happy i helped, so that answer is useful to others, you should accept it and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same kind of situation, jmx won't load. Only the error was different, I got: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

This was fixed by installing Java SE 1.7.0.67

Answer (score 0):

Please check your .jmx file there might be some code deleted....
I was facing same problem...but after looking into my .jmx file i saw there some code is deleted by my team members...