# jmeter Exception while importing jmx

Tags: exception, automation, jmeter

JMeter Exception while importing `jmx`. `Jmx` is automated and its throwing an exception as shown in below:

[image]

Please suggest step.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a plugin. To resolve this go [HERE](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) and download appropriate jar which you then put to ***lib/ext*** folder.

BTW, you should try to find answer on StackOverflow before asking questions! Issues like this are common and have many helpful answers...

Like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759977/conversion-error-when-opening-jmx-file-from-jmeter-2-7-in-jmeter-2-11) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011162/jmeter-error-on-opening-script)...

Answer (score 0):

First, you must install [VariablesFromCSV](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/VariablesFromCSV/) plugin, before importing the `jmx` file into `JMeter`

I suggest using [Plugin Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) for installing JMeter plug-ins from `JMeter GUI` itself

Comment: best way to say thanks is by accepting the answer :) (click on tick mark available next to the answer, to accept)