# JMeter error when opening my Test Plan - Unexpected error - see log for details

Tags: jmeter

I cannot longer open my test plan that I worked on yesterday. I get the following error message: "Unexpected error - see log for details".

I've tried to apply the solution proposed here: [jmeter error on opening script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011162/jmeter-error-on-opening-script) but I had no luck finding the line that caused the problem.

Do I have to completely redo this test?

Here is the log file:

**jmeter.log**

```
2018-03-12 09:42:26,407 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US
2018-03-12 09:42:26,419 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: user.properties
2018-03-12 09:42:26,427 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: system.properties
2018-03-12 09:42:26,433 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2017 The Apache Software Foundation
2018-03-12 09:42:26,433 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 3.3 r1808647
2018-03-12 09:42:26,433 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_151
2018-03-12 09:42:26,433 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
2018-03-12 09:42:26,433 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Windows 10
2018-03-12 09:42:26,433 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
2018-03-12 09:42:26,433 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=10.0
2018-03-12 09:42:26,434 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252
2018-03-12 09:42:26,434 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =3793747968
2018-03-12 09:42:26,434 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =4
2018-03-12 09:42:26,437 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States)
2018-03-12 09:42:26,437 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States)
2018-03-12 09:42:26,437 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=D:\Automation
2018-03-12 09:42:26,437 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =D:\Automation\bin
2018-03-12 09:42:26,438 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =D:\Automation\bin
2018-03-12 09:42:26,573 INFO o.a.j.g.a.LookAndFeelCommand: Using look and feel: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel [Metal, CrossPlatform]
2018-03-12 09:42:26,576 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties
2018-03-12 09:42:27,357 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2018-03-12 09:42:27,358 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2018-03-12 09:42:27,997 WARN o.j.r.PluginManager: Found JAR conflict: D:\Automation\lib\ext\jmeter-plugins-xml-0.1.jar and D:\Automation\lib\jmeter-plugins-xml-0.1.jar
2018-03-12 09:42:27,997 WARN o.j.r.PluginManager: Found JAR conflict: D:\Automation\lib\ext\jmeter-websocket-plugin-0.4.1.jar and D:\Automation\lib\jmeter-websocket-plugin-0.4.1.jar
2018-03-12 09:42:29,466 WARN o.j.r.Plugin: Unable to load class: com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.oauth.OAuthSampler
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampler2
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.Plugin.getJARPath(Plugin.java:193) [jmeter-plugins-manager-0.19.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.Plugin.detectInstalledPlugin(Plugin.java:107) [jmeter-plugins-manager-0.19.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.Plugin.detectInstalled(Plugin.java:96) [jmeter-plugins-manager-0.19.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.load(PluginManager.java:84) [jmeter-plugins-manager-0.19.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuItem$1.run(PluginManagerMenuItem.java:41) [jmeter-plugins-manager-0.19.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    ... 16 more
2018-03-12 09:42:29,624 INFO o.j.r.PluginManager: Plugins Status: [jpgc-graphs-basic=2.0, jpgc-graphs-additional=2.0, jpgc-autostop=0.1, blazemeter-debugger=0.6, jpgc-sense=3.4, netflix-cassandra=0.2-SNAPSHOT, jpgc-cmd=2.1, jpgc-graphs-composite=2.0, jpgc-csl=0.1, jpgc-functions=2.0, custom-soap=1.3, jpgc-casutg=2.5, jpgc-dbmon=0.1, jpgc-directory-listing=0.2, jpgc-graphs-dist=2.0, jpgc-dummy=0.2, jmeter.backendlistener.elasticsearch=2.2.2, jpgc-filterresults=2.1, jpgc-ffw=2.0, jpgc-ggl=2.0, bzm-hls=1.2, jpgc-httpraw=0.1, jpgc-sts=2.3, bzm-http2=1.1, jpgc-hadoop=2.0, jpgc-fifo=0.2, jpgc-jms=0.2, jpgc-jmxmon=0.2, jpgc-json=2.6, jpgc-graphs-vs=2.0, kafkameter=0.2.0, jpgc-lockfile=0.1, mqtt-sampler=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, jpgc-mergeresults=2.1, jpgc-pde=0.1, bzm-parallel=0.4, jpgc-prmctl=0.3, jpgc-perfmon=2.1, jpgc-plugins-manager=0.19, bzm-random-csv=0.6, jpgc-redis=0.2, jpgc-rotating-listener=0.2, ssh-sampler=1.1.1-SNAPSHOT, tilln-sshmon=1.0, jpgc-webdriver=2.3, jpgc-synthesis=2.1, jpgc-plancheck=2.2, jpgc-tst=2.2, jpgc-udp=0.3, jpgc-csvars=0.1, tilln-wssecurity=1.5, websocket-sampler=1.0.2-SNAPSHOT, websocket-samplers=1.1, jpgc-wsc=0.3, jpgc-xml=0.1, jpgc-xmpp=1.5.1, jmeter-core=3.3, jmeter-ftp=3.3, jmeter-http=3.3, jmeter-jdbc=3.3, jmeter-jms=3.3, jmeter-junit=3.3, jmeter-java=3.3, jmeter-ldap=3.3, jmeter-mail=3.3, jmeter-mongodb=3.3, jmeter-native=3.3, jmeter-tcp=3.3, jmeter-components=3.3, jpgc-standard=2.0]
2018-03-12 09:42:30,167 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2018-03-12 09:42:30,168 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2018-03-12 09:42:30,169 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2018-03-12 09:42:30,169 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2018-03-12 09:42:30,169 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2018-03-12 09:42:30,169 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2018-03-12 09:42:30,208 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2018-03-12 09:42:30,208 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2018-03-12 09:42:30,209 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2018-03-12 09:42:30,209 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2018-03-12 09:42:30,934 WARN o.a.j.g.ObjectTableModel: Header count=13 but classes count=11
2018-03-12 09:42:30,934 WARN o.a.j.g.ObjectTableModel: Header count=13 but writeFunctor count=11
2018-03-12 09:42:31,279 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.assertions.BSFAssertion
2018-03-12 09:42:31,365 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.extractor.BSFPostProcessor
2018-03-12 09:42:31,386 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.BSFPreProcessor
2018-03-12 09:42:31,489 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: Exception checking for keytool existence, will return false, try another way.
2018-03-12 09:42:31,681 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\keytool'
2018-03-12 09:42:31,682 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file D:\Automation\bin\proxyserver.jks
2018-03-12 09:42:31,799 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BSFSampler
2018-03-12 09:42:31,828 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='D:\Automation\bin'
2018-03-12 09:42:31,868 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoSourceElement
2018-03-12 09:42:31,868 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.sampler.MongoScriptSampler
2018-03-12 09:42:31,869 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_qos]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,869 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_at_most_once]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,870 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_at_least_once]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,870 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_exactly_once]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,870 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_client_types]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,870 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_blocking_client]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,870 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_async_client]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,870 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_message_input_type]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,870 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_message_input_type_text]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,870 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_message_input_type_file]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,875 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_qos]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,875 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_at_most_once]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,875 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_at_least_once]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,875 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_exactly_once]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,875 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_client_types]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,875 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_blocking_client]
2018-03-12 09:42:31,876 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [mqtt_async_client]
2018-03-12 09:42:32,130 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.timers.BSFTimer
2018-03-12 09:42:32,146 INFO o.a.j.g.u.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.BSFListener
2018-03-12 09:42:53,776 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Load: Loading file: D:\Automation\bin\test.jmx
2018-03-12 09:42:53,777 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='D:\Automation\bin'
2018-03-12 09:42:53,915 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2018-03-12 09:42:53,918 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2018-03-12 09:42:53,920 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 3.2
2018-03-12 09:42:53,922 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: D:\Automation\bin\test.jmx
2018-03-12 09:42:54,064 WARN e.l.j.w.WebsocketSampler: Detected Maciej Zaleski's WebSocket Sampler plugin is installed too, which is not compatible with this plugin (but both can co-exist).
2018-03-12 09:42:54,292 WARN o.a.j.g.a.Load: Unexpected error. java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:89) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:281) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.getCondition(IfController.java:177) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.IfControllerPanel.configure(IfControllerPanel.java:98) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:147) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:113) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:517) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:194) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:131) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.LoadRecentProject.doActionAfterCheck(LoadRecentProject.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:65) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
2018-03-12 09:53:08,580 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Load: Loading file: D:\Automation\bin\test.jmx
2018-03-12 09:53:08,580 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='D:\Automation\bin'
2018-03-12 09:53:08,581 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: D:\Automation\bin\test.jmx
2018-03-12 09:53:08,727 WARN o.a.j.g.a.Load: Unexpected error. java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:89) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:281) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.getCondition(IfController.java:177) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.IfControllerPanel.configure(IfControllerPanel.java:98) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:147) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:113) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:517) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:194) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:131) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.LoadRecentProject.doActionAfterCheck(LoadRecentProject.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.doAction(AbstractActionWithNoRunningTest.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:65) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
```

Thank you

---

**SOLUTION (that worked for me):**

For some reason, JMeter 3.3 corrupted my test file. In my test plan I had a few

"User Defined Variables" with the Value declared like:

```
"${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}File_Name.ini"
```

Solution was to open the .jmx file with a text editor and remove all user_defined_variables because the path was changed within the code.

**Good** code snippet:

```
 <elementProp name="SettingsFile" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">SettingsFile</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}File_name.ini</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
```

Was changed to:

```
<elementProp name="SettingsFile" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">SettingsFile</stringProp>
            <org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty>
              <name>Argument.value</name>
              <testIteration>118</testIteration>
              <cacheValue>C:\Automation\bin\File_Name.ini</cacheValue>
            </org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
```

I don't yet know why, but there are new tags like testIteration and the actual value for the path was changed to the full path (within the file).

Also, besides this, I got a new error telling me "Cannot compile the tree - see logs for details".

Removing the bad code and putting back the values fixed the problem. I consider switching to JMeter 4.0 and re-write all my tests again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did you find any solution.. I am facing the same issue again and again.. I have so many user-defined variables wont be possible to update manually every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION (that worked for me):**

For some reason, JMeter 3.3 corrupted my test file. In my test plan I had a few

"User Defined Variables" with the Value declared like:

```
"${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}File_Name.ini"
```

Solution was to open the .jmx file with a text editor and remove all user_defined_variables because the path was changed within the code.

**Good** code snippet:

```
 <elementProp name="SettingsFile" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">SettingsFile</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}File_name.ini</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
```

Was changed to:

```
<elementProp name="SettingsFile" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">SettingsFile</stringProp>
            <org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty>
              <name>Argument.value</name>
              <testIteration>118</testIteration>
              <cacheValue>C:\Automation\bin\File_Name.ini</cacheValue>
            </org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
```

I don't yet know why, but there are new tags like testIteration and the actual value for the path was changed to the full path (within the file).

Also, besides this, I got a new error telling me "Cannot compile the tree - see logs for details".

Removing the bad code and putting back the values fixed the problem. I consider switching to JMeter 4.0 and re-write all my tests again.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTPSampler2` was removed as a part of [Bug 60727](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60727) so you won't be able to use it with JMeter 3.3.

If you really need this plugin you will have to downgrade to [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31), it can be downloaded from [JMeter Archives](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/) page.

Comment: I do understand that and I will remove the plugin. But I was able to run and modify my test plan yesterday and I only modified some queries, nothing related to HTTPSampler2. Now, I am not able to open it again.